# Реализация интеллектуального указателя из книги А. Александреску

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

В настоящее время я занимаюсь чтением книги А. Александреску - "Современное проектирование на С++". Меня заинтересовала глава 7, темой которой является интеллектуальный указатель и его реализация.

Андрей сначала описывает, что такое интеллектуальный указатель, затем начинает описывать его реализацию от простого к конечному виду, затрагивая темы выбора стратегий владения, операторов взятия адреса, неявного приведения к типам обычных указателей, равенство неравенство, отношения порядка и т. д.

И я, в свою очередь, изучая материал, хочу получить полную картину описываемого указателя, но в книге эта информация даётся на уровне отдельного рассмотрения различных вопросов, которые я упомянул выше, и получается, что "пазл" не хочет сходиться. Не знаю, может быть это я такой тугой.

Мой вопрос заключается в том, может кто-нибудь знает, где можно найти полное описание данного интеллектуального указателя, включая стратегии в виде целостного кода или я слишком многого хочу?

Гугление особых результатов не принесло. Я точно пытался найти, честно.

Comment: @Abyx отчего же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный код к книге можно  найти [здесь](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.Download) либо гуглить по словам "Александреску loki". Детали реализации в книге хорошо раскрыты.

Comment: Может стоит скопировать какую-нибудь часть кода в ответ?

Comment: там тоны кода, под разные компиляторы (кстати, старые компиляторы). Не вижу смысла копировать.

Comment: так просто какой-то ответ ссылка получается :) хотя в вопросе ссылку и просили

Comment: В ответе есть ключевое слово - loki. То есть, на самом деле достаточно только его.

Comment: Да, вообще, если приглядеться, то там есть реализация этого класса, но всё равно, когда читаешь книгу, ну никак не получается собрать всё, что там описано в этой главе в то, что есть в исходниках по ссылке.